# Is it safe to scan a struct of N members of same type as an array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, scanf

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct V2f {
    float x, y; } V2f;
```

On my machine (64-bit Lubuntu 15.10) I can scan it using this function without any problems:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool scan_struct_as_arr(void *dst, int n, size_t sz, char *format) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if(!scanf(format, (char *) dst + i * sz)) {
            fputs("Failed to scan struct as an array", stderr);
            return false; } }
    return true; }
```

How much is this behaviour portable and why?

Could one trust this code if only variables of size 4 or 8 are used?

Comment: Safe or portable? Which is your question about?  Both? They are not exactly the same thing.  Nonportable constructs can be perfectly safe. (Safe here, not safe over there.)

Comment: Both. How safe and how portable it is.

Comment: Alignment is implementation defined, so there may be padding bytes.

Comment: Looks like a security failure: passing a format string unchecked, not using `const` qualifier, relying on a specific layout&endianess, wildly casting types (what is your problem with automatic type checking?). If some co-worker gave me such code, it would be high time for a serious talk.

Comment: Vector types like ones defined in `arm_neon.h` has a well defined structure and (I believe) is safe for this use, because it has well defined relationship to an array equivalent. I guess this should also be the case fro gcc vector extensions.

Comment: @user3528438: OP asks about standard compliance and portability. Additionally, that is not a machine-specific type, but a `struct` without any such guarantees.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how do you think a format-string for the given `struct` would look like? You only pass one argument to `scanf`, but have to read two values. This is an XY-problem. You might want to checkout nanopb or similar (de)serialisation libraries (or write your own).

Comment: @Olaf format string would be `%f`, and it would be scanned `n` times.

Comment: @SomeGuy: You should provide a [mcve]. Anyway, my clear advice will not change: this is awful code, hard to maintain and eror-prone at best. It also is not portable at least. If it invokes UB may be discussed, but not the other issues. In short: **do not**! Use proper (de)serialisation, that is an XY-problem with a much better solution (see nanopb for a better approach).

Comment: Definitely the weirdest code formatting I've seen this week.

Comment: @royhowie: It is fitting for the semantics;-{. But you should see more code, if you really think this is very bad. Welcome to the Coding Style Horror Show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is not safe or portable:

> #### C.11 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> 14. Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in an implementation defined
>       manner appropriate to its type.
> 15. Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
>       reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. ... There may be unnamed
>       padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

A given implementation may decide that for structures, every other float should be 16 bits away from the previous float, while for arrays it leaves them contiguous.

The more portable solution would be to just pass in the addresses, either as an array, or variable arguments:

```
bool scan_addr_array (void *addrs[], size_t N, const char *fmt);
bool scan_addr_va (const char *fmt, ... /* NULL terminated */);
```

Comment: But floats are 32-bit wide, not 16-bit wide. So no padding, right? Or at least, no padding on 99% of devices?

Comment: 48 bit machine with 32 bit floats

Answer (score 1):

Not safe, not portable: conversion from `struct V2f *` to `void *` and then to `char *` invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I thought every pointer type can be converted to `char*`? I am more worried about `scanf` writing to a `char*`
.

Comment: While I agree this is terrible code, I'm not sure if it really is UB if the scanned data matches the type of the original pointer (yet I have no idea how a proper format string would look like), Can you elaborate? (No discussion this code is a no-go)

Comment: @cad: maybe it can (I think so, but `void` was introduced into the language, among other things, because of conversion problems). The issue is a `char *`inside the scanf to access objects of type `struct V2f`.

Comment: So you mean that what I mentioned that `scanf` writes to a `float` through a `char*`?

Comment: Yes, any pointer to an object type can be converted to `char *`.  The result of such a conversion is well-defined (C2011 6.3.2.3/7).  One could perhaps argue that converting through an intermediate `void *` makes it problematic, but I'm inclined to reject that interpretation.

Comment: [C2011 6.2.5p28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28) does not specify compatability between pointers to struct and pointers to char.

Comment: @cad: As I would refuse code like that IRL, I'm actually curious about the chain of proof this is **technically** UB. I think this might even be **technically** allowed. There are just too many definition holes in the standard when it comes to `void *` and `char *`. So I try to view the original object's type and what `scanf` actually reads. That's why I'm very much interested in the format string for the given `struct`. It's more a matter of [6.5p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6).